# How does ..y.. work in R and in which contest can I use it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I've been using R for more than a year now. Often I've seen the symbol `..y..` being used, but I've not been able to find any documentation explaining how it exactly works.

In particular, recently I've used it to create labels on a `stat_summary` object. This is the code to plot a short timeseries (3 rounds of an experiment) which shows the duration of the activity of prawns in each round; the `stat_summary` serves to show if in general activity decreases or increases, for infected and uninfected prawns.

```
plot_activity <- ggplot(data = grouped_activity_gathered.df, aes(as.integer(Round), duration.Activity, group = PrawnID))

plot_activity <- plot_activity + geom_line(aes(color = increasing.Activity_factor)) 

plot_activity <- plot_activity + stat_summary(aes(y = duration.Activity, group = Infected, linetype = Infected), fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1)

plot_activity <- plot_activity + stat_summary(aes(y = duration.Activity, group = Infected, label=round(..y..,2)), fun = mean, geom = "text", size = 5, vjust = -0.25)

plot_activity <- plot_activity + theme_bw()

plot_activity
```

While this is the result:

[Plot created by ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jzFN.png)

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this curiosity of mine.

Comment: That's the `y` aesthetic from the call to `ggplot()` that created the plot. It is equal to `duration.Activity` as set in that call.

Comment: The information you might be looking for is in `?ggplot2::after_stat`. In particular, the use of `..varname..` is discussed in the details section.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas and @teunbrand for answering! Yes, I did understand that `y` was substituting for `duration.Activity`, but I wasn't understanding what the `..` were doing.  I see now that `..` is actually a function, equivalent to `after_stat()`, and that it acts on one of the stages of plot mapping - which I didn't know it happened on different stages.